# How to get this HTML Table textarea's value using JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I've tried some suggestions, but no success so far.

I'm getting `null` when trying to get this `textarea` value while going through the table and I don't know exactly why:

```
function savePo(user, origin) {
  user = 'user';
  origin = 'Trim';


  let date = new Date();
  options = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    second: 'numeric',
    hour12: false,
    timeZone: 'CST'
  };

  let timeStamp = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', options).format(date).toString();
  timeStamp = timeStamp.replace(",", "");

  const tableRows = document.querySelectorAll("#tableRows tr");

  let tableData = [];
  if (origin == 'Trim') {
    tableData = [...tableRows].map(r => {
      let td = r.querySelectorAll("td");
      return [...td].map((c, j) =>
        j == 2 ? c.value : //THIS IS THE LINE WHICH IS NOT WORKING PROPERLY
        j == 7 ? c.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0].checked :
        j == 6 ? c.innerText :
        c.querySelector('input').value)
    });
    console.log('Table Data: ' + tableData)
  }
}
```

[Here is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/8b17utw2/36/#&togetherjs=8pzp9FRwGs) in case you feel like pointing where the flaw is.

Appreciate it!

Comment: While a link to an external resource might be helpful, question on this site should be self-contained. Considering this, please add [mcve] directly into the question body, you might use [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/1595451) for HTML/JavaScript/CSS executable code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of a textarea element, instead of `innerText` of the parent element use `value` of such textarea element.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('td textarea').value
console.log(text)
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <textarea name="articuloField" id="articulo" rows="2" cols="65" wrap="soft">Testing the textarea value field which never seems to work!!!!!!!!!!</textarea>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just found out another way to get it in the context above: ```c.textContent``` applied to the column of choice.